# Is it possible to embed an HTTP basic username/password in a Paypal IPN notification URL?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am building a site and it is currently protected by an HTTP Basic Auth username and password.

I want to test integration with Paypal IPN.

In the Paypal Sandbox account for my test seller, I specified my IPN Notification URL in the form:

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS/?QUERY_PARAMS
```

I have confirmed that this URL works correctly when I load it in an incognito Chrome window.

When I do a test purchase, Paypal does not seem to send the HTTP Basic Auth headers and the IPN notification fails because it can not authorize.  I have also tested this using the IPN tester in the Paypal developer tools.

Is there a way to tell Paypal to send the necessary auth headers or do I have to reconfigure on the server side?

Comment: You don't need this. PayPal IPN already provides a message verification system. Don't roll your own.

Comment: I'm not worried about message security.  This site is in dev mode and I can't allow public access.  I _could_ allow the IPN queries through some Apache conf gymnastics, but it would be easier if Paypal's IPN agent could send the HTTP Basic auth creds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible according to PayPal documentation, but if you are asking about real-world scenarios usually you have proxy-server in front of/as your web-server which handles simple HTTP auth and you can set up exclusion rules for your PayPal IPN urls. For example if you use Nginx, yourdirectives will look like:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

location /paypal/ipn {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}

location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /example/.htpasswd;
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
location @proxy_to_app {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost;
            break;
    }
}
```

}